# loading fixtures for django tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, fixtures

I want to use some fixtures in my tests.

I have `cms_sample` app and a fixtures folder inside with: `cms_sample_data.xml`

I use the following in my `test.py`:

```
class Functionality(TestCase): 
    fixtures = ['cms_sample_data']
```

I do **use `TestCase` of `django.tests` and not `unittest`**.

But the fixtures are not loaded. What am I missing?

Comment: Try running with python manage.py test api --verbosity 2 

It might give a clue where it is looking.

Comment: OK. I see that he checks for initial_data fixtures, but he is not looking for the cms_sample_data fixture. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this fixture work when loaded manually?

Comment: where is it located on filepath?

Comment: The file works with loaddata. it located under cms_sample/fixtures/cms_sample_data.xml

Comment: Something similar is happening to me. But in my case is raising an exception. loaddata works.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem too - did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I had a written and forgotton about a custom loaddata management command, which was being called instead by django.TestCase!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot the xml-extension?

```
class Functionality(TestCase): fixtures = ['cms_sample_data.xml']
```

Comment: Since you checked this as the answer, can you please explain?

Comment: He thought it not be like it was, but it do.

Comment: -1 for failing to justify adding the extension. Django will look for fixtures of any extension when you don't provide one; adding the extension only makes it easier for Django to locate that specific extension by narrowing the search to files with that exact name.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your cms_sample_data file is error.
you can use this comand:
manage.py loaddata cms_sample_data

to check the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while learning about this subject on Django's docs. How I solved it was changing the format file that stored my fixture to the proper format. Originally, I saved the fixture was an ordinary text file with the name "test_db.json". Once I realized this, I changed the ".txt" file into a ".JSON" file. It began to load the fixture on its own once I typed in the "./manage.py test" command.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multiple databases? If so, your test might need to set the [multi_db property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#multi-database-support):

```
multi_db = True
```